# Want to provide only one time password on all servers

Tags: linux, bash

I have created same ssh passphrase key from one main box to 10 servers, I want to deploy some commands and copy files from main box to other 10 servers with one time key. I don't want to use the passpharse key all time for logging on all servers.. i want to give key one time for on all servers..

Can anyone provide a small script or simplest method to accomplish?

```
[root@dasari9~] cat hostnames
localhost
remotehost
Sivaranjani
exlusive
[root@dasari9~]#
```

These all are hosts, I want to run some commands from main box to all above hosts.

Comment: Use the `ssh-agent`.

Comment: Have you considered an ssh key?

Comment: yes.logging with ssh key

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly and you can connect to your hosts without being prompted, you can run a bash for loop:

```
for host in $(cat hostnames); do ssh $host <command to run>; scp <file to copy> $host:/path/to/target; done
```

Comment: Could you please check again my question , with one time key can able to deploy files on all servers..

Comment: I'm not familiar with one-time keys, but I found postings about one-time passwords.  Perhaps this is more a question of the particular technology you are using for the one-time key, then about linux and bash? Or give more info on what you are doing to set up a one-time key.